# Multiple countdowns jQuery and organize them depending the time left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

I want to create a website with multiple countdowns activated by a click, some of them have different time, others the same. I need to organize them depending the time left. When one finish I need to return it to his original countdown value, so you can click again.

To understand better (I don't need the effects, I made them only for the example): https://i.stack.imgur.com/S65dy.gif

---

I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/m19aojmu/

Each countdown works independently of the others.

HTML

```
<div class="element" id="el1"><b>Elm 1</b> <span class="timeout">10</span> segundos</div>
<div class="element" id="el2"><b>Elm 2</b> <span class="timeout">100</span> segundos</div>
<div class="element" id="el3"><b>Elm 3</b> <span class="timeout">5</span> segundos</div>
```

Javascript

```
function timer(selector) {
    var self = $(selector);
    var sec = parseInt(self.find('span.timeout').text());

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        sec--;
        if (sec >= 0) {
            self.find('span.timeout').text(sec);
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}


$("body").on('click', '.element', function() {
    timer(this);
});
```

While each countdown have a different id (el1, el2, el3 ...) I don't know to detect which of them finished, therefore I don't know how to add a class when it start and end.

About the ubication, what should I do? Different classes for each location with position absolute?

I know it's a lot, but some help will be great.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Edit: Progress https://jsfiddle.net/m19aojmu/5/ (I'm new in the website, so I can't post more than 2 links in a post because of my reputation, that's why I use a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agusitn you code its like 95% correct, but you are setting the `.text()` into the `sec variable` wich is `0` or `-1`

Lets change the code a little bit

First lets take the actual value of the `span` DOM Element.

```
    var actualTime  = $('span.timeout').html(); 
   console.log("the actual value when click is " + actualTime)
```

Later on the `if statement` we check when the actual span text its `equal to 0`

```
else if($(this).find('span').text() <= 0) {
            console.log(sec)
            var text =  self.find('span.timeout').text(actualTime);
            console.log(actualTime)
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
```

and when the `.text()` its `=== to 0`, we set the `actualTime variable` to get back to the actual time.

here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m19aojmu/9/)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to organize them depending the time left? For example, I click 100 seconds, then I click 10 seconds... now 10 seconds its last, but it should be up to 100... hope you understand